# Can a grizzly bear be kept as a pet?

Tags: pet-selection, exotic-pets, domestication

I saw that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVMBdi4dgME) a few time ago. It shows the story of Brutus the Grizzly which is living as a pet with his owner.

I take grizzlies as dangerous animals and so I think the grizzly must have been castrated, had his fangs and claws removed ( and so this makes the whole thing quite cruel ).

Is it possible to have a grizzly bear as a pet? Is it legal?

Comment: Legal is a question of geography, what is legal in one place is not always legal in different place.  Where do you want to know if it is legal to keep a grizzly?  Can you expand on what types of interactions you envision you would have with a grizzly?

Comment: I never wanted myself to have a grizzly as a pet, that is not the question.

Answer (score 4):

Bears can not be domesticated. They can be *TAMED*, but that means continuing to deal with them as wild and dangerous animals. Specialized training and licensing are absolutely required,  plus living far enough from other people and maintaining enough control and site security to not be a danger to anyone but yourself.

Unless you're going to make this your profession, and spend the years and money on doing so, forget it. There are very good reasons we keep the pets we do.